# Designing and developing a header for many screens - android

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a header wich looks like that in my app:
[image: header]

I want it to be from left side to the right side from the screen.

What are the exact steps I have to make it look good on as many devices as possible?

Comment: Obtain as many devices as possible, to perform your testing on.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an ActionBar and is available as from API Level 10+. However there is an excellent library with which you can also use it in lower librarys. Look for ActionBarSherlock:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Have images for each density( LDPI, MDPI, HDPI and XHDPI)
2. Use a relative layout.